# $f(z)=2|z|^2+3$. Show that $f$ is differentiable at $z = 0$. Is $f$ analytic at $z=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

$f(z)=2|z|^2+3$.

Show that $f$ is differentiable at $z = 0$. Is $f$ analytic at $z=0$?

I tried:

Since $z=x+iy$, we have:

$f(z)=2(x^2+y^2)+3=2x^2+2y^2+3$

Then, use Cauchy-Riemann equations to get:

$u(x,y)=2x^2$ and $v(x,y)=2y^2+3$

$u_x=4x$ and $u_y=0$

$v_x=0$ and $v_y=4y$

Thus, $4x=4y$ and $0=0$ which holds for $z = 0+i0=0$. This means that $f$ is differentiable and analytic at $z=0$.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Actually $u(x,y) = f(x,y) = 2 x^2 + 2 y^2 +3$ and $v(x,y) = 0$ since $f$ is a purely real function. It won't be analytic.

Comment: For a complex function to be analytic at some point it must be that it is analytic on certain (open) neighborhood of that point...

Comment: @SebastianSchulz, so if $f$ contains $i$, then it is analytic at $z=0$? Also, with the correction, would it be $4x=0$ and $4y=0$ which holds for $z=0$, and so, $f$ is differentiable at $z=0$?